# Jenkins unable to run "terraform apply --auto-approve"

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I need to launch few instance on AWS using terraform script, i am automating the whole process using jenkis,

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    tools {
        terraform 'terraform'
    }
     stages{
        stage('Git Checkout'){
            steps{
                git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'gitlab id', url: 'https://gitlab.com/ndey1/kafka-infra'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform init'){
            steps{
                sh 'terraform init'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform apply'){
            steps{
                sh 'terraform apply --auto-approve'
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

First 2 stage is ok but getting the error in 3rd stage

```
+ terraform apply --auto-approve
[31m╷[0m[0m
[31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mNo configuration files[0m
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m│[0m [0m[0mApply requires configuration to be present. Applying without a
[31m│[0m [0mconfiguration would mark everything for destruction, which is normally not
[31m│[0m [0mwhat is desired. If you would like to destroy everything, run 'terraform
[31m│[0m [0mdestroy' instead.
[31m╵[0m[0m
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

but when applying the code from local its perfectly working even in the stage of terraform init its working but in stage of terraform apply its failing

and while i apply ls -ltra in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/infra-kaka/terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc. this is the output

```
total 60
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 1036 Aug 11 14:58 vpc.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 1710 Aug 11 14:58 variables.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 1551 Aug 11 14:58 security_group.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins   68 Aug 11 14:58 provider.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  420 Aug 11 14:58 output.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 1674 Aug 11 14:58 oregonkeypair.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  235 Aug 11 14:58 kafka.config
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 1732 Aug 11 14:58 instance.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  630 Aug 11 14:58 hosts.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 6658 Aug 11 14:58 hosts-ssl.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins   94 Aug 11 14:58 ansible.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  630 Aug 11 14:58 all.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins    0 Aug 11 14:58 .gitkeep
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Aug 11 14:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 jenkins jenkins 4096 Aug 16 12:35 ..
```

Comment: Where is your main.tf file in the repository?  Before the terraform apply command can you run a `ls -ltra`?  If the tf files are in the root of the repo I feel like you may need to wrap the init and apply in a `dir('kafka-infra') { ... }`

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli comment is correct. You retrieve the root module config with git, but then `apply` outside of the directory of the config. You need to change directory into the config, preferably with the `dir('kafka-infra') { ... }` in the comment, before executing `terraform` commands.

Comment: @Niladri Dey if the solution works for you please accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Proposed Issue

*I will edit this depending on your response to my comments*

I am fairly sure the issue is that `terraform apply` command cannot find your configuration file. To troubleshoot this I would suggest you run a `ls -ltra` above your `terraform apply` command to see if the terraform configuration file exists in the same directory you're running the commands in contains your tf file.

## Sample Code #1

> This assumes there is a terraform/ directory in your current directory that contains your tf file

You can add the relative path of the directory containing of your tf file to the end of the apply command as follows:

```
terraform apply terraform/
```

## Sample Code #2

> This code also assumes you have a terraform/ directory in the root of your repository that contains your tf file

This option executes those commands by changing your current directory to the terraform/ directory

```
dir('terraform') {
  terraform init
  terraform apply --auto-approve
}
```

You obviously will need to update your directory paths accordingly.  As stated you can run a `pwd` to see where you are and a `ls -ltra` to see what files are in your current directory

Comment: Actually still facing issue, before applying terraform. init am entering the dir where the code is but still its showing - The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working
with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files

Comment: I don't know what "You may begin working with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files" means, but you can't run a terraform apply in a directory without tf files.

Comment: all the .tf files are in the dir infra-kafka/terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc , there only i am running the command , that is why i used cd terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc before running terraform init

Comment: this is the file location where all the .tf files located and i am cloning them from git in this location : /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/infra-kaka/terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc

Comment: Before the terraform apply command do an ls -ltra and post the output to your original post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236049/discussion-between-niladri-dey-and-chris-maggiulli).